# Tekerik RadGrid sum expression for child data

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgrid

Here is my situation:

I am using telerik with winform.

I have a dataset with a relationship between two tables. These two tables are loaded in an hierarchical way in the radgridview.

Now, in the child grid, I have a price column for each row.

I am trying to create a calculated field in the master grid view which will reflect the total of the prices in the child grid. The code I am using is like the following:

```
...
GridViewTemplate child = rdGvView.MasterTemplate.Templates[0];
rdGvView.MasterTemplate.Columns["TotalPrice"].Expression = "Sum(child.prodPrice)";
....
```

But this gives me an error which says {"Field name: child does not exist in the template."}

I am using the sum expression from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.80).aspx

where prodPrice is the column name of the table in the dataset which is imported in the radgrid.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs the answer to this question, it is available [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/radgrid-sum-expression-for-child-data.aspx).

Comment: I have 3 child grids and in the main grid two column which represents summary of total amount from child tables. I tried to use Evaluate method as described in the link. The result is good for the first child but for second child it gives column not found error.